# input a graph's edges

Tags: python, graph, pyscripter

```
import sys
import itertools
nodes=input("enter the number of nodes")

q=[]

q.append(x)

r=0
vertices=[]
a=0

for i in xrange(0,nodes):
    vertices.append(a)
    a=a+1

def inputgraph():
    cordinates=[]
    cor1=input("enter x or -1 to exit:    ")

    while cor1!=-1:
        cor2= input("enter y")
        cordinates.append((cor1,cor2))
        cor1= input("enter x or -1 to exit:    ")

    return cordinates

def main():
    cordinates=inputgraph()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my python code to input the edges of a graph into a list. here we have to enter the edge (x,y) as two separate inputs. is there any way to input it as one input??

Comment: can you post something we can actually run?  here, `nodes` is undefined, no call is made to `inputgraph`, etc.

Comment: @dbliss i believed that's optional, because snippet are like pseudocode, to be understood without running it.

Comment: @Yeo snippets *can* be like pseudocode; in this case the snippet was not effective pseudocode.  thanks for updating, GayathriBS!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cor1, cor2 = [int(x) for x in raw_input("enter x y: ").split()]
```